# Converting autocall libraries to stored compiled macros

Tags: sas, sas-macro

We have hundreds of macros across several autocall libraries that I'd like to compile using the `MSTORE` facility.

The problem is that some of those libraries are used on other sites - and we don't want to add `/STORE` to every definition, as then it is *required* to use the `MSTORED` option.

I guess the answer is to add `/* /STORE */` at the end of every `%macro` statement, so that the .sas program files can be updated with a regular expression (or some other text replacement technique) on every redeploy, but this seems like a messy workaround.

Is it possible / in some way supported, to compile regular (unmodified) autocall macros and store the definitions?  Eg by `%inc`'ing each one and saving the work macro catalog, or something like that?

Comment: What's your motivation for doing this? The overhead of compiling macros is usually tiny.

Comment: It is performance, and due to some big macros, which I suspect are being recompiled many times due to use of `dosubl` and `run_macro` within the process.  Saves about 1.5 to 2 seconds overall, in a 43 second (average) session.

Comment: I stand corrected, the time saving in the end was negligible.  Perhaps it was prior use of `run_macro`, whereas now I tend to use `dosubl` (there was definitely a bigger impact last time I measured).

Comment: ok, testing complete - 0.8 seconds saved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't say definitively that this isn't possible, but I can report that I tried to do the same thing some time ago and got stuck on the same point. I was also unable to find any way of doing this other than adding `/store` to every `%macro` statement.

I vaguely remember that I was able to upload the `work.sasmacr` catalogue from one session to another on the same machine (after first compiling a few autocall macros to populate it), but the other session didn't recognise the macro definitions from transferred catalogue even though the appropriate options were set for using stored compiled macros.

My motivation was different from yours - I was looking for a way to define a macro in one session and execute it in another without saving it in an autocall folder or `%including` it in both sessions - but the conclusion was the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think your hunch is correct and it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here was the approach I took for compilation (of course there are many alternative ways).  The locations to query can be extracted from:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(sasautos));
```

The approach relies on macros being closed off with `)/*/STORE SOURCE*/;` as follows:

```
%macro some_macro(var1=x, var2=y
)/*/STORE SOURCE*/;
```

The SAS code has to be a program, as you can't create a stored compiled macro from within a macro.

```
/* set mstore options */
options mstored sasmstore=yourlib;

/* get list of macros */
/* taken from macrocore library */
/*https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/base/mp_dirlist.sas*/
%mp_dirlist(path=/location/one,outds=in1)
%mp_dirlist(path=/location/two,outds=in2)

/* set up a temporary fileref */
filename tmp temp;

/**
 * write each source macro to the fileref
 *  and switch on the STORE option 
 */
data want;
  set in1 in2;
  infile dummy filevar=filepath end=last ;
  file tmp;
  do until(last);
    file tmp;
    input;
    if _infile_=')/*/STORE SOURCE*/;' then put ')/STORE SOURCE;';
    else put _infile_;
  end;
run;

%inc tmp;  /* compile macros */
filename tmp clear;  /* clear ref */
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem that you had?

First compile all of your autocall macros. Say you have a fileref named MYMACS that points to the directory with the source code.

```
%include mymacs(macro1,macro2,.....);
```

You might use a program to search for all of the source files so that you could automate generating the %include statement(s).  Or you could use a datastep and copy all of the source files into a single temporary file and include that.

```
filename src temp;
data _null_;
  infile "&inpath\*.sas" ;
  file src ;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
%inc src ;
```

Then copy the WORK catalog to you a new location.  Note that the name is different if you are running SAS on an application server. In that case try copying from `WORK.SASMAC1` instead of `WORK.SASMACR`.

```
libname out base "&path";
proc catalog cat=work.sasmacr et=macro ;
  copy out=out.sasmacr ;
  run;
quit;
```

You can test if it worked by clearing your current work macro catalog, so you know SAS is not finding the macro there, and setting options to point to the new catalog of compiled macros.

```
proc catalog cat=work.sasmacr kill force ;
quit;
options mrecall mstored sasmstore=out ;
```

Then trying to run one of the copied compiled macros.

Now start up a new session and try using the compiled macros in that session.

Comment: I didn't try actually doing that as wasn't sure if there were known / undocumented issues with it (is just not described anywhere).  My process is built now, but will give this approach a crack if the issue comes up again..

Comment: fyi, the `mrecall` option is superfluous

Comment: The `mrecall` is useful if you had tried to call a macro before and it had failed to find the macro. At least that is true with `autocall` libraries, not sure if it matters for stored compiled macros.